# Show cgridview data based on condition

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

Is this possible to show cgridview data using condition. like only show those data where status=1.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-details-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name1',
    'p_address1',
    'phoneno',
    'email1',
    'owner_name',
    'position', 
    'status'
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{delete}',

     ),
),
```

));

The table have status 0 and 1. I only want those listings which status is 1.

UPDATE:
if i changed search method like this

```
$criteria->compare('status',1);
```

It's worked perfectly. But is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

You show data from model in CGridView. You can add conditions as criteria.
For example in your model in search method add

```
$criteria->addCondition('status = 1');
```

Comment: I did not notice your update. But i prefere my solution. Because in semantic way i add condition, and you hardcode comparison to one way